# What is Sunni’s view about the conflict between suggestions (imarat) and practical principles?

Tags: sunni, shiism, fiqh

In case of conflict between suggestions (imarat) and practical principles, Shia Islam largely believe in precedence of the imarat. So my question is: “What's the view by other schools (Sunni scholars)?"

For example, if a suggestion comes into conflict with a preservation (istis'hab) or an option-grant (takhyir), what do the jurists of the four school have to say?

---

**Note:** the definition of **imarat /اماره** can be considered as the following explanations:

- The presumptions in source methodology in Islamic jurisprudence
- The evidence which leads to a speculative reasoning
- The indication leading to a speculative reasoning
- The credible suspicion sign/proof

**Source:** [www.wikifeqh.ir](http://www.wikifeqh.ir/%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D9%87)

Comment: I'm afraid you must elaborate and explain what is meant by imarat with an example, as i neither could read Farsi nor know about a similar term in Arabic. As Imarah الإمارة https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emirate would be related to Khilafah. And your explanation so far is more about juridical matters than about leadership.

Comment: You are right. It is factually a heavy word... as more explanation: The Presumptions in Law or the legal circumstantial evidence... It is a fiqh related expression. I assume you can find it in Arabic Fighh as well.

Comment: Well it seems this is what you refer to http://ar.wikifeqh.ir/wiki/topic.php?key=%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9 and I've seen some text fragments quoting similar quotes as in this article. But I think -and I hope I got it right- some sunni scholars prefer to speak about maqassid a-Shri'a مقاصد الشريعة the goals of shari'a when trying to explain why something is haram or halal this is only a result of a fast over reading of the article.

Comment: Uh-huh, what you said can be helpful. Jazak Allah Khaira.

Comment: Here some of my findings (in Arabic) http://shamela.ws/browse.php/book-2048/page-213  https://books.google.de/books?id=EONGCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT1096&lpg=PT1096&dq=%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9+%D9%81%D9%8A+%D8%A3%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84+%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87&source=bl&ots=8Dvv6QT3qK&sig=7QN-mFUze9bZp4mDDPXbTIHz70Y&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi0mJqA4PLNAhXMbBoKHa6cAIg4ChDoAQhCMAU#v=onepage&q=%D8%A3%D9%85%D8%A7%D8%B1%D8%A9%20%D9%81%D9%8A%20%D8%A3%D8%B5%D9%88%D9%84%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%81%D9%82%D9%87&f=false أمارة has also been defined as علة = reason http://www.almaany.com/ar/dict/ar-en/%D8%B9%D9%84%D8%A9/